# Apple push notification enhanced format

Tags: iphone, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

Does anybody know how to get error response from Apple push notification service when enhanced version of protocol is used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Apple documentation if we are using enhanced version of Push protocol we can get error response from channel, error respose format:

> COMMAND(1 byte)|STATUS(1 byte)|ID(4
>   byte)

statuses:

> ```
> 0: 'No errors encountered'
> 1: 'Processing error'
> 2: 'Missing device token'
> 3: 'Missing topic'
> 4: 'Missing payload'
> 5: 'Invalid token size'
> 6: 'Invalid topic size'
> 7: 'Invalid payload size'
> 8: 'Invalid token'
> 255: 'None (unknown)'
> ```

here example code:

```
...
socket = SSLSocket (
    socket.socket()
    , ssl_version = ssl.PROTOCOL_SSLv3
    , certfile
)

socket.connect(apnsHost, apnsPort)

len_written = connectionContext.write(socket)

errors = []

# Wait for input from socket
inputready = select.select ([socket], [],[], 1)[0]

if inputready:
        replyBlock = channel.recv (6)

        errors = [] #will be filled with error responses
        while replyBlock:
            #error-response packet
            #COMMAND(1)|STATUS(1)|ID(4)
            command, status, id = struct.unpack_from('!BBL', replyBlock)

            if status != 0:
                errors.append((command, status, id))                

            replyBlock = channel.recv (6)
```